# Coexistance of primitve and reference data types in Java

Tags: java, types, primitive-types

I always asked myself this question : why did Java designers have introduced both primitive and reference types in their language. In other words, why would exist two data types which can fullfil the same goal, such as (int & java.lang.Integer), (float & java.lang.Float) ... Could anyone please explain me this issue ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Java has primitives because :

> 1. They are fast.  (when compared to Objects)
> 2. They have less overhead. (when compared to Objects)
> 3. They actually *make life easier for people with C/C++ background* and gives them the same *feel* (almost).

Java has Wrappers because :

> 1. In certain data structures like *Collections*, only objects are allowed to be added because when doing Garbage Collection, the GC
>      treats all these things only as Objects and then performs operations
>      on them.
> 2. Using Wrappers (Objects) instead of *primitives* in *Collections* is more of a design choice because it allows *general behavior* of
>      methods. For example `equals()` , `contains()` on collections work on
>      the basis of *method overriding* which cannot be done on *primitives*.

Answer (score 0):

Primitives are faster than reference types (almost unnoticeable in small loops, but in large operations, the difference is clear), make reading code for people with c/c++ backgrounds easier, and in general, are a better, optimized fit for general-purpose operations with basic types.

Consider however that some parts of Java (Collections, Generics, Reflection... ) require classes and not basic types, so the wrappers (plus boxing and unboxing) were added for that. In addition, wrappers are nullable, while basic types are not, which might also be required in certain operations.